# Can't visit anchored links in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, blogs

I'm trying to build my theme for a school project and I'm using wordpress to set up a blog.

I don't have intentions of sharing this theme so all of the website design is already premade.

The problem occurs when I try to enter the `blog.php` file from my navigation. My homepage is `index.php` file from which i navigate to the blog site. Everytime I do so the index page refreshes instead of opening the `blog.php` file, but the browser search bar shows the directory location as `blog.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress does not work on a process of just make a file and it can be used as a page. Instead, it uses template structure. Meaning blog.php is not a page, it is a template (if you have setup the file structure correctly). Putting link through a menu to "blog.php", confuses WordPress and it just displays the default page of the site. You should make each page through WP "Pages" section.

StackOverflow hates WordPress questions. WordPress has its own help forum. I suggest googling for it and ask questions there.

If I mistook your question here are some helpful links:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development